# How to print out time statistics of a whole query with a loop?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to compare hash performance of SHA2 (256 vs 512) on our server.
I've tried

```
SET STATISTICS TIME ON
GO

DECLARE @Counter INT = 0;
DECLARE @Result nvarchar(4000);

DECLARE @HashThis nvarchar(4000);  
SET @HashThis = CONVERT(nvarchar(4000),'Some dummy text.'); 

WHILE @Counter <= 10000
    BEGIN 
        SET @Result = HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', @HashThis);
        SET @Counter = @Counter +1
    END 

--SELECT @Result

SET STATISTICS TIME OFF
GO
```

which seems to return an independent time statistics for each loop, having highest time resolution to ms.
I want to know how long exatly does the whole query last. Or perhaps, RAND() function should be used?

Comment: Just store start and end time in a variable?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to measure it like this:

```
DECLARE @Counter INT = 0;
DECLARE @Result nvarchar(4000);

DECLARE @HashThis nvarchar(4000);  
SET @HashThis = CONVERT(nvarchar(4000),'Some dummy text.'); 

-- timing for SHA2_256
DECLARE
      @startTime_256 datetime2(7) = GETUTCDATE()
    , @endTime_256 datetime2(7);

WHILE @Counter <= 10000
    BEGIN 
        SET @Result = HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', @HashThis);
        SET @Counter = @Counter +1
    END

SET @endTime_256 = GETUTCDATE();


SET @Counter = 0;

-- timing for SHA2_512
DECLARE
      @startTime_512 datetime2(7) = GETUTCDATE()
    , @endTime_512 datetime2(7);

WHILE @Counter <= 10000
    BEGIN 
        SET @Result = HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', @HashThis);
        SET @Counter = @Counter +1
    END

SET @endTime_512 = GETUTCDATE();

-- results
SELECT
      DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, @startTime_256, @endTime_256) AS [SHA2_256_Milliseconds]
    , DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, @startTime_512, @endTime_512) AS [SHA2_512_Milliseconds]
    , 1.0*DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, @startTime_256, @endTime_256)/DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, @startTime_512, @endTime_512) AS [SHA2_256_TimesFasterThen_SHA2_512];
```

I have found it to be rather dynamic on my local instance. However, increasing the number of iterations (for example, up to 100 000) and running it multiple times you can get the general idea of how long it should take to do these calculations.